# Javascript SpriteSheet not working

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I have been having some trouble with displaying a sprite sheet on a simple canvas. For debugging purposes I have taken the code out from my main code so that I can work on just one small file. The sprite sheet loads up next to the canvas but the canvas does not display the sprite itself. 
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="36" style="border:1px solid" onload="draw_hello()" ></canvas>

<img id="helloSprites" src="Tux-Hello.png">

<script>
//hello sprite
var x=0;
var y=0;
var f=0;
var w=32;
var h=32;
var mycanv=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=mycanv.getContext("2d");

//helloImage.src = "images/Tux-Hello.png";
//var helloImage = new Image();


var hello=document.getElementById("helloSprites");
function draw_hello() {
    setInterval(drawHello,200);
}
function drawHello() {
        ctx.fillStyle="#292";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,mycanv.width, mycanv.height);
        ctx.fillStyle="#aaa";
        ctx.fillRect(0,25,mycanv.width, mycanv.height);
    if (x>=(mycanv.width)) {  
        x=0;
    }
    x+=2;
        f++;
    // draw the car 
        if (f==2) {
          f=4;
        }
        if (f==6) {
          f=0;
        }

    ctx.drawImage(hello, w, f*h, w, h, x, y, w, h);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach your `onload` to the `body` element and not the `canvas` element.

You're probably calling onload--and therefore calling draw_hello() before the img element is fully loaded.